# Photoshop scripting crop away x pixels from every side of document

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a lot of images like this one which need to be processed as a batch:

[image: unprocessed image]

What I'm trying to accomplish is to crop away the border on every side, but here's the catch: trimming doesn't work because the color in every corner of the image is not black but white, so instead I'm trying to crop away about 5 pixels on every side. I've written some code to do just that but there seems to be an error somewhere resulting in funny, mirrored and wrongly cropped images:

```
function cropLayerToBounds(){
var layer = activeDocument.activeLayer; //Grab the currently selected layer

// get height and width
var actualHeight = layer.bounds[2]-layer.bounds[0]; //Grab the height
var actualWidth = layer.bounds[3]-layer.bounds[1]; //Grab the width

// calculate desired height and width
var desiredHeight = actualHeight - 5;
var desiredWidth = actualWidth - 5;

// not sure if necessary
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var halfWidth = (desiredWidth/2);
    var halfHeight = (desiredHeight/2);
    var centerX = (doc.width/2);
    var centerY = (doc.height/2);

// error seems to be here

   // tried this
   var bounds = [0,0,desiredHeight,desiredWidth];

   // and this
   var bounds = [(centerX-halfWidth),(centerY-halfHeight),(centerX+halfWidth),(centerY+halfHeight)];

    doc.crop(bounds);


}
```

The images i process this way look somewhat like this:

[image: processed image]

Comment: It's unclear from your question what your exact requirement is. Is your requirement to crop an image x no. of pixels from all sides (i.e. remove the black border which is 5 pixels wide)? Is there a reason why you are applying it to the active layer (that's the part that is confusing me)? Can you clarify?

Comment: yes exactly it is to remove 5 pixels on every side, but i think i have found the problem: the ruler unit has to be set to pixels like this: // set units to pixels - important
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following script utilizes a custom function named `cropCanvas` that will meet your requirement.

It's not necessary to access the `activeDocument.activeLayer`, as cropping affects the whole document (i.e. canvas).

**Example gist:**

```js
var document = app.activeDocument; // Assumes a document is active.

// Obtain original ruler units prefs.
var originalRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;

// Set the ruler units prefs to pixels.
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

/**
 * Crops the canvas by x number of pixels equally from all sides.
 * @param {Number} [amountOfPixels=0] - Number of pixels to crop.
 */
function cropCanvas(amountOfPixels) {
    amountOfPixels = amountOfPixels || 0; // Defaults to zero.

    // Obtain height and width of canvas.
    var canvasWidth = document.width.value;
    var canvasHeight = document.height.value;

    // Define the new bounds.
    var newBounds = [
        amountOfPixels,
        amountOfPixels,
        canvasWidth - amountOfPixels,
        canvasHeight - amountOfPixels
    ];

    // Crop the canvas. 
    document.crop(newBounds);
}

// Invoke the `cropCanvas` function passing
// in the `amountOfPixels` value.
cropCanvas(5);

// Reset ruler prefs.
app.preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;
```

**Notes:**

1. The script initially obtains Photoshop's current ruler units via `app.preferences.rulerUnits;` and assigns it to the `originalRulerUnits` variable, before setting the ruler units to pixels.
2. The `cropCanvas(...)` function has one parameter, namely `amountOfPixels`. This enables the function to be invoked with one argument specifying the amount of pixels to crop the image by. For example:

   ```js
   cropCanvas(5); // Crops 5 x pixels from all sides.

   cropCanvas(25); // Crops 25 x pixels from all sides.
   ```
3. Finally, Photoshop's ruler units are reset to its original unit.

---

**Additional considerations**

By not setting `app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;` can result in incorrect cropping as per the example shown in your question. However, Photoshop's *ruler origin* can also produce unexpected results too when it's coordinates are *not* set to `(0,0)`.

To illustrate this potential issue carry out the following:

1. Open an image PhotoShop.
2. Show the rulers by typing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>*(macOS)*, or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>*(Windows)*
3. Change the ruler’s zero origin by positioning the pointer/cursor over the intersection of the rulers in the upper-left corner of the window, and drag diagonally down onto the image. A set of cross hairs will appear, marking the new origin for the rulers. Further explained [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/rulers.html)
4. Then run the example gist provided above.

As you can see, when the ruler's zero origin is not set to zero, undesired cropping can occur.

The ruler origin can be reset to the default value, (i.e. `0,0`), by double-clicking the upper-left corner of the rulers.

***Important:*** Now, this should not be too much of an issue for you as you mention in your question *"...need to be processed as a batch."*, which suggests your final script will be opening images one-by-one programmatically (i.e. automated). When images are opened the ruler origin defaults to `0,0` so no undesired cropping should occur.

However, in a scenario whereby a feature of your script is to allow it to be run on an image which a user has opened and may have defined a new ruler origin. Then your script will also need to reset the ruler origin to zero (i.e. `0,0`).

**Example gist for handling non-zero ruler origin:**

```js
var document = app.activeDocument; // Assumes a document is active.

// Obtain original ruler units prefs.
var originalRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;

// Set the ruler units prefs to pixels.
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

/**
 * Photoshop API doesn't provide a method to reset the ruler origin to [0, 0].
 * This get the cuurent ruler origin so we can offset the value.
 * @returns {Object} with properties `x` and `y` offset for rulers.
 */
function getRulerOffset() {
    var ref = new ActionReference();

    ref.putEnumerated(
        charIDToTypeID("Dcmn"),
        charIDToTypeID("Ordn"),
        charIDToTypeID("Trgt")
    );
    var desc = executeActionGet(ref);

    var rulerPositionX = desc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID('rulerOriginH')) / 65536;
    var rulerPositionY = desc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID('rulerOriginV')) / 65536;

    return {
        x : rulerPositionX,
        y : rulerPositionY
    }
}

/**
 * Crops the canvas by x number of pixels equally from all sides.
 * @param {Number} [amountOfPixels=0] - Number of pixels to crop.
 */
function cropCanvas(amountOfPixels) {
    amountOfPixels = amountOfPixels || 0; // Defaults to zero.

    // Obtain height and width of canvas.
    var canvasWidth = document.width.value;
    var canvasHeight = document.height.value;

    // Obtain current ruler x and y offset.
    var rulerOffsetX = getRulerOffset().x;
    var rulerOffsetY = getRulerOffset().y;

    // Define the new bounds.
    var newBounds = [
        amountOfPixels - rulerOffsetX,
        amountOfPixels - rulerOffsetY,
        canvasWidth - amountOfPixels - rulerOffsetX,
        canvasHeight - amountOfPixels - rulerOffsetY
    ];

    // Crop the canvas. 
    document.crop(newBounds);
}

// Invoke the `cropCanvas` function passing
// in the `amountOfPixels` value.
cropCanvas(5);

// Reset ruler prefs.
app.preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;
```

The revised script (above) now includes in addition to the previous gist:

1. A new function, namely `getRulerOffset`, that returns the current `x` and `y` coordinates of the ruler origin. Unfortunately, Photoshop does not provide an API which can be called to reset the ruler origin so we have to obtain the current values instead.
2. In the `cropCanvas` function we now additionally create two new variables (`rulerOffsetX` and `rulerOffsetY`), and their values are subtracted when defining the `newBounds` variable.

---

**Another solution utilizing the `resizeCanvas()` method**

Another way to meet your requirement is to utilize the `resizeCanvas()` method instead of the `crop()` method. I actually prefer this approach because the position of the *ruler origin*, (as discussed in the *"Additional considerations"* section), has no affect.

Here is a gist for that:

```js
var document = app.activeDocument;

// Obtain original ruler units prefs.
var originalRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;

// Set the ruler units prefs to pixels.
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

/**
 * Resizes canvas removing x number of pixels equally from all sides.
 * @param {Number} [amountOfPixels=0] - Number of pixels to remove.
 */
function removePixelsFromAllSides(amountOfPixels) {
    amountOfPixels = amountOfPixels || 0;

    document.resizeCanvas(
       document.width.value - (amountOfPixels * 2),
       document.height.value - (amountOfPixels * 2),
       AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER
    );
}

// Invoke the function passing in the `amountOfPixels` value.
removePixelsFromAllSides(5);

// Reset ruler prefs.
app.preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;
```

Comment: Thank you dear photoshop scripting wizard!

Comment: @RobC thanks for great answer!! I'm totally new to PS scripting.. I've got couple of questions:
1) What's the difference between crop vs resize? Somehow I thought that crop makes sure that objects on photo will stay at the original scale and resizing will make them smaller?
2) How to undo a crop? 

I'm writing script where I need to generate 10s of files of different sizes for an original file. So my approach: crop, save crop, undo crop, get to next size info and repeat. Does that sound correct? Thank you! ‍♀️

Comment: Hi @DashaLuna - **1)** _"Crop"_ removes x no. of pixels from all sides of the canvas. The last example in my answer utilizes the [`resizeCanvas`](http://jongware.mit.edu/pscs5js_html/psjscs5/pc_Document.html#resizeCanvas) method to essentially _"Crop"_ the canvas. I'm not certain what you're wanting to achieve - it may be that you need to utilize the [`resizeImage`](http://jongware.mit.edu/pscs5js_html/psjscs5/pc_Document.html#resizeImage) method. I suggest you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you're stuck.

Comment: @DashaLuna - **2)** I just wrote  [this gist](https://paste.ee/p/2XHp4) that utilizes a custom `undo` function using [HistoryStates](http://jongware.mit.edu/pscs5js_html/psjscs5/pc_HistoryStates.html)). The gist demos _cropping_ the active image by various pixel amounts and saves each resultant image as PNG format into the same folder where the original image resides.  Your approach _"crop, save crop, undo crop, get to next size info and repeat"_, does sound correct to me... It's just the nuances of whether you want to _"crop"_ or _"resize"_ the image that I don't fully grok from your comment.

Comment: @RobC thank you so much for taking the time and writing up the code, very kind of you - it helped me a lot! Aha, I've researched canvas vs image size - I now understand what's going on. Resizing canvas size works great and easier to be able to use `AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER` instead of crop bounds math. I'm totally new to Ps, so all things are new atm.I wonder if it would be cleaner to duplicate active document, do the canvas resizing and then just close the duplicate document instead of dealing with history states 

Comment: @DashaLuna - you're welcome. The programmatic [`resizeCanvas`](http://jongware.mit.edu/pscs5js_html/psjscs5/pc_Document.html#resizeCanvas) method is akin to manually choosing _"Image" > "Canvas Size"_ from the Menu Bar in PS. The [`resizeImage`](http://jongware.mit.edu/pscs5js_html/psjscs5/pc_Document.html#resizeImage) method is akin to manually choosing _"Image" > "Image Size"_ from the Menu bar. Yes, it's certainly possible to _"duplicate [the] active document, do the canvas resizing and then just close the duplicate document"_. I suggest timing both ways to discover which is most efficient.